# Port Forwarding by libssh2 not working when iOS App goes to background

Tags: ios, objective-c, portforwarding, libssh2

I have an iOS app which is serving as a **SSH Client** and I am working on **Port Forwarding** feature (local, remote, dynamic) with **libssh2** library.

The one issue I am facing is when the App goes to **background** that time port forwarding **stops working**.

Is there any solution or suggestions for this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: No, when an app is suspended all of its network operations stop.

Comment: But as soon as I goes to background, the request not fire and port forwarding not working.

Comment: That's correct - Technically when an app isn't in the foreground it is "suspended" (but this is often, incorrectly called "being in the background"). Background execution is different. The are only select background execution modes on iOS for things like location. There is no persistent network background execution mode.

Comment: iOS 13 limits the background time to about 20 seconds though my app is not performing like this. Port forwarding request just stops as soon as app enters in background mode. I have checked other apps which provides port forwarding functionalities and for 20 seconds their session remains active and after enabling port forward, enter the app in background mode and load the request in browser then it works perfectly. So, my concern is that why my app is not behaving like that same behaviour

Comment: You need to call `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` to obtain that background execution time